# What should I do if I post any private credentials in my question by mistake?

Tags: support, privacy

On Stack Overflow I have posted a question which contains some private credentials of mine.

Now I have edited the question and remove those credentials but it can be seen by others when someone clicks my edit. Presently I have deleted the question.

Stack Overflow doesn't allow duplicate questions to be asked, even if the question is been deleted.

Please guide me a way to re-ask the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag the post for moderator attention explaining what has happened.

Moderators can redact revisions, so they can remove the credentials from all copies of the post - once redacted, they will be gone from the site and will not be recoverable by anyone on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Flag the post for moderator attention. They will be able to edit out the information entirely, without it being visible by others.